# Oracle 12.2.0.1.0 CLOB output (unreadable) (HUGECLOB) is not supporting Oracle report6i

Tags: oracle11g, oracle12c, oracleforms, oraclereports

I have a column contains more than 50000 characters.

After migrating from Oracle 11g to Oracle 12.2.0.1.0 this field is showing as (HUGECLOB) but this is not supported with Oracle 6i reports,

Comment: Is this just showing as `HUGECLOB` in Toad or another client? The underlying type is still just a CLOB. So are you actually experiencing an error from Reports, and if so what is it? (Is Reports 6i compatible with Oracle 12c? No idea...)

Comment: I'm getting this error WPPackage.WPException: ORA-01410: invalid ROWID
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 860
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: in toad it shows HUGECLOB